# How to organize events over time

Tags: owl, ontology, protege4

I'm developing an ontology in Protégé that allows you to search for movies in various cinemas according to different criteria (date, start time, actor …). 
The problem can be generalized to how to organize any type of event over time. But let's stick with movies. Given a film, I want to organize the shows of the film by giving it a list of values like this: date - start times - price.

Example: FilmX

- 2018-01-06 4PM 6PM 8PM 10PM 12PM 10$
- 2018-01-07 4PM 6PM 8PM 10PM 12PM 10$
- 2018-01-08 4PM 6PM 8PM 10PM 10$ 8$
- 2018-01-09 4PM 6PM 8PM 10PM 10$ 8$
- …

I thought about defining a custom Data Type able to represent this type of information, but I do not think it is the best solution. Especially because I would like to be able to query the ontology using this information efficiently.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Why don't you `owl:import` this [Time Ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/)? It might be an overkill for your purposes but will do the job.

Comment: Don't forget, custom datatypes won't be considered by any reasoner like Pellet or HermiT. The OWL built-in datatype for date/time is `xsd:dateTime`.

Comment: I decided to model each specific show as a separate entity, with its date, start time and price. In this way the number of individuals grows very fast but considering the domain, seems to me the best choice both from the conceptual point of view and performances.